# How does scrapy handle yield items in parse function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been kind of new to generators and yields so excuse me if I get some explanation or wrong info in the way. To explain the problem I want to give an example of what I want to ask, normally to yield a value within a loop inside a function (which is then called a generator because of the yield) it will only go through the entire loop if I call it as an iterable or inside a loop or next function, here's an example:

```
def parse():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

Now if I want to print the entire range (you can consider the range a list or something else, doesn't necessarily have to be a range) or numbers to 10, I could do it in multiple ways:

```
x = parse()
list(x)
```

or

```
for i in parse():
    print(i)
```

and so on, the main point is I need to iterate on the generator to be able to get all the values or to have the inner loop (inside the parse function) to finish all of its iteration yields

now comes the question, scrapy does the same way but different a bit which confuses me, here's a code that was an example in digital ocean which explains how to use scrapy

```
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote-spdier'
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        QUOTE_SELECTOR = '.quote'
        TEXT_SELECTOR = '.text::text'
        AUTHOR_SELECTOR = '.author::text'
        
        for quote in response.css(QUOTE_SELECTOR):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css(TEXT_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css(AUTHOR_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

I understand that for each start_url, it calls the parse function and only once with the response of the page, now consider I have multiple products in one page and I only have one start_url, so my parse function is only called once (this is an important key detail to follow up)

now the for loop will iterate on all the products in the page ( imagine that response.css(product-item) which is a class for each product in the page) and will yield the object once, here's where I'm confused, if I run scrapy spider with the previous code I will get all the products in that page, how is it that scrapy can return all the products if the parse function is only called once for this page? to give context, calling a generator with next() for example will return only the first value of the generator's yield in loop so how does this work?

Note: I'm kind of trying to understand how scrapy parse works under the hood (does it call parse in a loop under the hood, does it call next(parse()), how is it done?) and how is this implemented to have better understanding of yields and generators

Comment: the simple answer is that it is called in a loop

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in its documentations or anywhere else doing that? I would assume knowing how yield and generators are used to generate the items required that it would be called in a loop, but that's speculation on my end knowing how normally this works, but (sorry for saying this but chatgpt had a different opinion and I don't usually rely on its info as it is most of the time fake things)

Comment: No i don't think it is mentioned in the documentation.  The actualy more complicated answer is that it kind of depends on the situation, and even then the iterator usually get's passed through layers of middleware and is returned through twisted defereds. But eventually it does get iterated over in some kind of loop.

Comment: So eventually, no matter what the situation is, it will definitely be used in a loop. I went through the code itself in the repo of scrapey but I wasn't sure where I'm supposed to look, although it all seems real complex to grasp and probably will have multiple layers as you mentioned so it's easy to get lost, but if it eventually does loop on that function then this makes complete sense, thank you so much for clarifying this I was going insanse trying to figure what's going on with it, appreciate your help!